# Source Tree can't find SASS files in order to commit

Tags: css, git, sass, atlassian-sourcetree, precompiling

I am working in a project. I started to use SASS for it, but Source Tree cannot find these files, only the CSS files compiled from the .sass. Any suggestions or fixes?

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file in your main folder? If so, open it and check if there is some exclusion about SASS

Comment: This what I have in ProjectFolder/.git/gitignore.txt

**/.sass-cache
**/.sass-cache/*

Comment: check your `.gitignore` file

Comment: Could be a bit more precicse about what I am supposed to check in that file?